# finding rank of matrix easily

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I was reading "Linear Algebra" by Hoffman and Kunze and I came across this,
(since I don't have enough reputation to post pictures, I am quoting straight from the book)

> $$
>  A-I=\begin{bmatrix}4&-6&-6\\-1&3&2\\3&-6&-5\\\end{bmatrix}$$
>   We know $A-I$ is singular and obviously $\operatorname{rank}(A-I)\geq2$. Therefore, $\operatorname{rank}(A-I)=2$.

My question is, how is it obvious that \begin{equation}\operatorname{rank}(A-I)\geq2\end{equation}

I know we can find the RREF and determine the rank. But is there any other way we can find it by just looking at the matrix?

Comment: If one row of a matrix is not a multiple of the other, then matrix has at least two linearly independent rows and thus has rank at least two, which is why the author says this is obvious

Comment: In general, there is no way of finding the rank of a matrix that is dramatically easier than finding the RREF

Comment: The first two rows of $A-I$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @eepperly16 Thanks a lot, that really helped

Comment: @sudh98 Please, if you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the rank is $1$ if and only if one of the columns is non-null and all the other columns are that one times a scalar. That's obviously *not* the case here,

Answer (score 0):

because the first and the third row of $A-I$ become equal and the second is not a multiple of them